# Change the style of a substring in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html-table

I am trying to change the color of some hardcoded substrings that can be present in a v-for loop used to populate a table.

My loop is the following:

```
              <tr v-for="(src, index) in contentArray.content" :key="src.id">
                <td class="myclass1" >{{ src.something1 }}</td>
                <td class="myclass2">{{ src.string }}</td>
              </tr>
```

Let's say that I want to apply a specific color on a substring of `src.string`.

For instance if `src.string` is:

```
This is a test
```

I want to be able to apply a color on the word 'test'.

The substring that I want to color will not be present in every string of the loop.

I have a subset of multiple hardcoded substrings that I want to color.

How can I do that ?

I tried to play with another v-for loop with the `split` method, or with a `v-bind:class` but I can figure how to do this ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string in the template, and conditionally render a `span` only for each matching word:

```html
<template v-for="w in src.string.split(/\s+/)">
  <span class="keyword" v-if="w === searchWord">{{w}} </span>
  <template v-else>{{w}} </template>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ExWKJYm)

*Note this solution limits the searchability of phrases (it searches only for single words).*

Alternatively, you could use a computed property that wraps only the target word(s) with a `span`:

1. Declare a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) (called `"computedContent"`) that preprocesses the `string` properties of `contentArray.content`, wrapping all target words with `<span class="keyword">`:

   ```js
   export default {
     computed: {
       computedContent() {
         const searchWord = this.searchWord.trim()
         if (!searchWord) return this.contentArray.content

         return this.contentArray.content.map(x => ({
           ...x,
           string: x.string.replace(new RegExp(searchWord, 'ig'), w => `<span class="keyword">${w}</span>`)
         }))
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update the template to use this computed property instead:

   ```html
   <tr v-for="(src, index) in computedContent" :key="src.id">
   ```
3. Use the [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) to bind the `td`'s `innerHTML` to `src.string`:

   ```html
   <td class="myclass2" v-html="src.string"></td>
   ```
4. In your component's `<style>` block, select `.keyword` to style it:

   ```html
   <style>
   .keyword {
     font-family: Monaco, sans-serif;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: blue;
   }
   </style>
   ```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjWXzgr)

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr v-for="(src, index) in contentArray.content" :key="src.id">
  <td class="myclass1" >{{ src.something1 }}</td>
  <td class="myclass2">
{{ src.string.includes('test') ? src.string.replace('test', `${<span :class={color: 'yourColor'}></span>}`) : src.string }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

You can check for the word you want to change with **.includes()** and replace that word with **.replace()** with the html tag and class you want

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string as you said then bind the class conditionally :

```
<td class="myclass2">
   <span v-for="substr in src.string.split(' ')" :class="{'someClass':substr==='test'}">
      {{substr}}
   </span>
</td>
```